# how to hard code prices in pinescript ? manully entering prices

Tags: pine-script

Hi is their any way I can hard code prices in PineScript. For example what I mean is I want to create an array or any variable that stores all my support and resistance levels that i have manully enetered.

like this

float [] prices = (1.3900,1.4000,1.4050,1.4100 etc)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var float[] prices = array.from(1.3900, 1.4000, 1.4050, 1.4100)
```

if you want to use inputs

```
p1 = input(1.3900)
p2 = input(1.4000) // etc

var float[] prices = array.new_float()
if barstate.isfirst
     array.unshift(prices, p1)
     array.unshift(prices, p2)
```

`barstate.isfirst` will make the values available from the first bar and thereafter for the script to access since it is `var` declared. Alternatively you can use `array.push()` instead if you want the order of the array in reverse.

Comment: Will give it a try! Thanks alot !!